# Unable to host WCF in IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, iis-8.5

I want to host WCF Service Application in IIS. I watch some video how to do that. Here is the step i tried:

1. On Visual Studio 2012. I created new WCF Service Application. (success)
2. Right click service1.svc -> View In Browser. (success)
3. After success to view the service in browser. I try to host this service in IIS. On the IIS, Right Click in the Default Web Site -> Add Application.

   [image: List item]
4. I browse this service by clicking browse in the IIS

   [image]
5. But it display error message:
   [image]

I did not make a change to the WCF Service Application. I keep it all default just like inside the video that i watch recently. Is there a problem with my IIS ? (I use IIS 8.5 by the way)

Answer (score 0):

Check framework on application pool.
Enable Directory browsing also.

Asp.net to IIS Registration:

Check if you are using 64 or 32 bit.

**Command Prompt:**

```
1. cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
2. aspnet_regiis -i
```

Comment: on the wcf file. The target framework i chose is 4.5.2. Meanwhile in in the IIS i choose 4.5. Is that okay ?

Comment: Try if it work. Anyway did you register asp.net in your IIS Server

Comment: i did not see register the asp.net part in the video tutorial. can you tell me step by step to register asp.net to iis server ?

Comment: Edited an answer above.